# Using RANK() or DENSE_RANK() to get the next value by Rank

Tags: sql-server, dense-rank

I have data within a SQL Server table where there is a single date column. This date is a "Transfer Date" for each LocationID in my database. I need to write a query where the TransferDate for one CustomerID becomes the StopDate. Additionally, the same TransferDate also becomes the StartDate for the next CustomerID in order of date. I could perhaps use RANK() or DENSE_RANK and OVER to order the results by LocationID and TransfDate. My question is how do I use RANK() or any other method to fetch the "next" TransferDate in my table as the StartDate for the next CustomerID.

Here are screenshots of the data in the table (Table1) and my desired result. The last value in the Table1 screenshot is a derived value from a related table to Table1 for which I am using a join to fetch that one additional row.

```
LocationID  CustomerID  TransferDate
------------------------------------
500007      109160      12/29/2009
500007      109160      2/9/2018
500007      99999999    2/13/2018
500007      100001      3/30/2018
500007      129615      4/8/2019
500007      100001      5/16/2019
500007      99999999    5/17/2019
500007      131458      12/31/9999
```

[image: Desired Result]

Results after using LEAD() and LAG():
[image]

Working DDL is below. One row with Customer '111706' is in the base table but my final query includes several other joins which results in this row being eliminated. Will that cause on issue? I am not sure when LEAD() or LAG() actually execute. I feel they execute before my join, rendering the rest of the dataset problematic.

```
create table Table1(
  Location char(15),
  Customer varchar(15),
  TransferDate datetime
  )
  
  insert into Table1 
  values
  ('500007','111706','2009-12-29'),
  ('500007','109160','2009-12-29'),
  ('500007','109160','2018-02-09'),
  ('500007','VACANT','2018-02-13'),
  ('500007','100001','2018-03-30'),
  ('500007','129615','2019-04-08'),
  ('500007','100001','2019-05-16'),
  ('500007','VACANT','2019-05-17');
  
select Location, Customer, TransferDate,
LAG(TransferDate,1,TransferDate) over (order by Location,TransferDate) as StartDate,
LEAD(TransferDate,1) over (order by Location,TransferDate) as StopDate
from Table1
where Location='500007'`
```

Comment: It sounds like you want [`LEAD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) OR [`LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) rather than `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`

Comment: Please post the actual version of SQL Server. What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return?

Comment: @GarethD yes, I definitely need to use LEAD(). Was not aware of it. Still trying to figure out how to suppress the NULL value in the last record.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: You can supply a default value to the `LEAD` function as the 3 argument, and this value will be used if there is no next row. So you could use something like: `LEAD(TransferDate, 1, t.SomeDefaultValue) OVER(PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY TransferDate)`

Comment: @GarethD thanks for the suggestion. I felt that the default value will lead to complications and decided to use a WHERE clause to suppress NULLs, given that this is only happening in the last row. But I am facing several issues with the starting records as well where I am getting multiple records. I decided to try and use LAG() and eliminated NULL values there as well. But LAG will give me a whole bunch of new problems, creating further complications. I've posted a screenshot of the results. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Can you post a small working DDL with sample data that reproduces the issues you are having? This will be much more useful than posting screenshots. For more information read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/1048425)

Comment: @GarethD I gave the DDL a shot! I am restricting this to only one Location. I have several thousand but did not want to further complicate the question.

Comment: @GarethD I guess I was wrong in using both LAG and LEAD in the same query. One of them had to be TransferDate. Once I figured that out, I think I might have resolved it. I'm still going through my query output with the full table to figure out if this works in all cases. Will update here one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the suggestion by @GarethD to resolve my issue. In my case, LAG() was the answer as I already had the next date available. Thanks for his help with this. I found some [good examples here](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-lag-function-overview-and-examples/).